# Dataflow batch vs streaming: window size larger than batch size

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Let's say we have log data with timestamps that can either be streamed into BigQuery or stored as files in Google Storage, but not streamed directly to  the unbounded collection source types that Dataflow supports.

We want to analyse this data based on timestamp, either relatively or absolutely, e.g. "how many hits in the last 1 hour?" and "how many hits between 3pm and 4pm on 5th Feb 2018"?

Having read the documentation on windows and triggers, it's not clear how we would divide our incoming data into batches in a way that is supported by Dataflow if we want to have a large window - potentially we want to aggregate over the last day, 30 days, 3 months, etc.

For example, if our batched source is a BigQuery query, run every 5 mins, for the last 5 mins worth of data, will Dataflow keep the windows open between job runs, even though the data is arriving in 5 min chunks?

Similarly, if the log files are rotated every 5 mins, and we start Dataflow as a new file is saved to the bucket, the same question applies - is the job stopped and started, and all knowledge of previous jobs discarded, or does the large window (e.g. up to a month) remain open for new events?

How do we change/modify this pipeline without disturbing the existing state?

Apologies if these are basic questions, even a link to some docs would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want arbitrary interactive aggregation queries on your data. Beam / Dataflow are not a good fit for this per se, however one of the most common use cases of Dataflow is to ingest data into BigQuery (e.g. from GCS files or from Pubsub), which *is* a very good fit for that.

A few more comments on your question:

> it's not clear how we would divide our incoming data into batches

Windowing in Beam is simply a way to specify the aggregation scope in the time dimension. E.g. if you're using sliding windows of size 15 minutes every 5 minutes, then a record whose event-time timestamp is 14:03 counts towards aggregations in three windows: 13:50..14:05, 13:55..14:10, 14:00..14:15.

So: same way as you don't need to divide your incoming data into "keys" when grouping by a key (the data processing framework performs the group-by-key for you), you don't divide it into windows either (the framework performs group-by-window implicitly as part of every aggregating operation).

> will Dataflow keep the windows open between job runs

I'm hoping this is addressed by the previous point, but to clarify more: No. Stopping a Dataflow job discards all of its state. However, you can "update" a job with new code (e.g. if you've fixed a bug or added an extra processing step) - in that case state is not discarded, but I think that's not what you're asking.

> if the log files are rotated every 5 mins, and we start Dataflow as a new file is saved

It sounds like you want to ingest data continuously. The way to do that is to write a single continuously running streaming pipeline that ingests the data continuously, rather than to start a new pipeline every time new data arrives. In the case of files arriving into a bucket, you can use `TextIO.read().watchForNewFiles()` if you're reading text files, or its various analogues if you're reading some other kind of files (most general is `FileIO.matchAll().continuously()`).

Comment: "but I think that's not what you're asking" -> Thanks, that was what I was asking. I'll definitely follow up on those functions. We do want to ingest continuously so they should be appropriate.